# How can I convert flout var (touch screen y pos) to vector2?

Tags: struct

I want scrolling my slider with touch screen in android , I have this code :

```
// for scroll
var scrollPosition : Vector2 = Vector2.zero;
//label style
var touch = Input.touches[0];
function OnGUI() {
windowMain = GUI.Window(1, Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height), WindowFunctionMain, " ");  
}
function WindowFunctionMain (windowID : int) {

scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(Rect (0,Screen.height/2,Screen.width,Screen.height/4+20),scrollPosition, Rect (0, 0, 650, 0)); 

if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    scrollPosition = scrollPosition +  touch.deltaPosition.y;

for (var i=0;i < ImgSliderProducts.Length;i++)
{
    GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(20+(i* 100),10,100,100), ImgSliderProducts[i],ScaleMode.ScaleToFit,true);
}

GUI.EndScrollView();
```

but in this line have error :  scrollPosition = scrollPosition +  touch.deltaPosition.y;

Operator '+' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'UnityEngine.Vector2' and a right hand side of type 'float'.
How can I solve this problem ?
TNX.

Comment: Your question title is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a float to a Vector2 doesn't make any sense. How would the Vector2 know which of its components you wanted to add the float to?

```
scrollPosition.y += touch.deltaPosition.y;
```

Or

```
scrollPosition += new Vector2(0, touch.deltaPosition.y);
```